# Registrar Header numa referencia de serviço SOAP em C#

Tags: c#, soap, header

Gostaria de um apoio. Estou com sérios problemas em um cliente. Tenho uma aplicação em C# que busca dados de um sistema e os envia dados para um serviço SOAP. Ocorre que esse serviço SOAP requer um cabecalho:

```
<soapenv:Header>
 <wsAutenticacao>
    <login>us1</login>
    <senha>b81476fc88f1a2a4</senha>
    <codigoEmpresa>1</codigoEmpresa>
 </wsAutenticacao>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Ao mapear pelo Visual Studio, não consigo localizar onde inserir os dados do cabeçalho. A solução não foi iniciada por mim e preciso dar continuidade no mesmo padrao.

Os serviços estao mapeados no app.config como Properties.Settings e nao como binding:

```
 <setting name="wsSGOSituacaoProjeto_SituacaoProjetoWSImplService"
                serializeAs="String">
   <value>http://ser:8080/erp/ws/situacaoProjeto</value>
 </setting>
```

A chamada na referência não contém nada a respeito do Header:

```
public ProjetoWSImplService() {
            this.Url = global::Integracao.SGO.Properties.Settings.Default.Projeto_ProjetoWSImplService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }

        public new string Url {
            get {
                return base.Url;
            }
            set {
                if ((((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(base.Url) == true) 
                            && (this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly == false)) 
                            && (this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(value) == false))) {
                    base.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                }
                base.Url = value;
            }
        }

        public new bool UseDefaultCredentials {
            get {
                return base.UseDefaultCredentials;
            }
            set {
                base.UseDefaultCredentials = value;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public event consultarProjetoCompletedEventHandler consultarProjetoCompleted;

        /// <remarks/>
        public event inserirCompletedEventHandler inserirCompleted;

        /// <remarks/>
        public event consultarCompletedEventHandler consultarCompleted;

        /// <remarks/>
        public event alterarCompletedEventHandler alterarCompleted;
```

A parte do código que esta dando erro por falta do header é a seguinte:

```
if (WebServiceSGO == null)
            {
                Iniciar("http://ser:8080/erp/ws/projeto?wsdl");
                //WebServiceSGO = new Integracao.SGO.wsSGOProjeto.ProjetoWSImplService();
            }
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var ret = WebServiceSGO.consultar(Param.Empresa, Param.EmpresaEspecificada, Param.UnidadeAdministrativa, Param.Datainicio, Param.DatainicioEspecificada, Param.Projeto, Param.AnoProjeto, Param.AnoProjetoEspecificado, Param.TipoProjeto, Param.Cliente, Param.ClienteEspecificado);
            return ToXML(ret);
```

retorno: "Falha no Login!"

Comment: de onde você pega os dados de login/senha/codigoEmpresa?

Comment: Foi me fornecido pela empresa que construiu o serviço. É uma informação estatica.

<soapenv:Header>
<wsAutenticacao><login>erp</login><senha>b814720948b6bf65e0b5a6fc88f1a2a4</senha><codigoEmpresa>1</codigoEmpresa></wsAutenticacao>
</soapenv:Header>

Comment: quis dizer se está num arquivo de configuração por exemplo? mas no seu caso acho que não vai ajudar, vou coloca uma resposta com um exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode setar o header assim:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("login", "us1");
client.Headers.Add("senha", "b81476fc88f1a2a4");
client.Headers.Add("codigoEmpresa", "1");
```

Comment: É um projeto pronto. Da forma que foi feito, a referencia nao deixa fazer essa operação vem como uma interface (vou tentar mostrar aqui):
public ProjetoWSImplService() {
            this.Url = global::Integracao.SGO.Properties.Settings.Default.Georede_SGO_wsSGOProjeto_ProjetoWSImplService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }   else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }  }    ...

Comment: outra parte do codigo e referencia:
 if (WebServiceSGO == null) WebServiceSGO = new Integracao.SGO.wsSGOProjeto.ProjetoWSImplService();
referencia:
         public ProjetoWSImplService() {
            this.Url = global::Integracao.SGO.Properties.Settings.Default.Georede_SGO_wsSGOProjeto_ProjetoWSImplService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
        ...

Comment: mas se o código está pronto, como vc vai adicionar o *header*? precisa editar o código

Comment: E que o serviço no qual estamos comunicando passou exigir headset com as credenciais.

Comment: Na verdade quis dizer, o projeto com código fonte já veio pronto. Eu tenho o código fonte comigo.

Comment: mas esses códigos que você colocou são um pouco diferentes do que está na pergunta, que simplesmente cria um `WebClient`... mas vamos lá, o proxy que usa para consumir o serviço é "WebServiceSGO" certo? Como você cria ele? Tem alguma coisa no seu Web.config, como endereço do serviço, ou você cria ele passando o endeeço?

Comment: vc tem um email? eu vou te passar o fonte.